# for loop skips iterations arbitrary

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a nested for loop inside a background thread in my app and I have a problem with for loop, it skips iterations, first for loop iterates through arraylist which contains arraylists of radiostations by genre and the second one iterates through arraylist of radiostations by genre, for example first for loop should iterate through arraylist that contains such genres: top hits, classic, 80s, 90s, RnB. And the app iterates top hits, 80s and 90s and thats all, it doesn't finish iterations.
Here is the code:

```
private final ArrayList<RadioStation> namesOfStationsOfTopHitsStations = new ArrayList<>();

private final ArrayList<RadioStation> namesOfStationsOfHipHopStations = new ArrayList<>();


private final ArrayList<RadioStation> namesOfStationsOfRockStations = new ArrayList<>();
private  final ArrayList<RadioStation> namesOfStationsOfElectronicStations = new ArrayList<>();
private  final ArrayList<RadioStation> namesOfStationsOf80sStations = new ArrayList<>();
private  final ArrayList<RadioStation> namesOfStationsOf90sStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> collegeRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private  final ArrayList<RadioStation> rockRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();

//radiostations by countries
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> namesOfStationsOfAustrianStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> namesOfStationsOfBelarusianStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> namesOfStationsOfAlbanianStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> belgiumRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> bulgarianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> croatianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> cyprusRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> czechRepublicRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> denmarkRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> estonianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> finlandRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> franceRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> germanianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> greeceRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> hungarianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> irishRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> italianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> latvianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> lithuanianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> netherlandsRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> norwayRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> polishRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> portugalRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> romanianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private   final ArrayList<RadioStation> russianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> serbianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> slovakianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> slovenianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> spanishRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> swedishRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> switzerlandRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();
private    final ArrayList<RadioStation> unitedKingdomRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();

private final ArrayList<RadioStation> ukrainianRadioStations = new ArrayList<>();




private final ArrayList<ArrayList<RadioStation>> totalStations = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            totalStations.add(namesOfStationsOfTopHitsStations);
            totalStations.add(namesOfStationsOfHipHopStations);
            totalStations.add(namesOfStationsOfRockStations);
            totalStations.add(namesOfStationsOfElectronicStations );
            totalStations.add(namesOfStationsOf80sStations );
            totalStations.add(namesOfStationsOf90sStations );
            totalStations.add(collegeRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(rockRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(namesOfStationsOfAlbanianStations );
            totalStations.add(namesOfStationsOfAustrianStations );
            totalStations.add(namesOfStationsOfBelarusianStations );
            totalStations.add(belgiumRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(bulgarianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(croatianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(cyprusRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(czechRepublicRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(denmarkRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(estonianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(finlandRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(franceRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(germanianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(greeceRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(hungarianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(irishRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(italianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(latvianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(lithuanianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(netherlandsRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(norwayRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(polishRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(portugalRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(romanianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(russianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(serbianRadioStations  );
            totalStations.add(slovakianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(slovenianRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(spanishRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(swedishRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(switzerlandRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(unitedKingdomRadioStations );
            totalStations.add(ukrainianRadioStations );

            final ArrayList<String> genresList = new ArrayList<>();
            genresList.add("Top Hits");
            genresList.add("Hip hop");
            genresList.add("Rock");
            genresList.add("Electronic");
            genresList.add("80s");
            genresList.add("90s");
            genresList.add("College radio");
            genresList.add("Classic Rock radio");
            genresList.add("Albanian radio");
            genresList.add("Austrian radio");
            genresList.add("Belarusian radio");
            genresList.add("Belgium radio");
            genresList.add("Bulgarian radio");
            genresList.add("Croatian radio");
            genresList.add("Cyprus radio");
            genresList.add("Czech radio");
            genresList.add("Denmark radio");
            genresList.add("Estonian radio");
            genresList.add("Finland radio");
            genresList.add("France radio");
            genresList.add("Germany radio");
            genresList.add("Greece radio");
            genresList.add("Hungarian radio");
            genresList.add("Irish radio");
            genresList.add("Italian radio");
            genresList.add("Latvian radio");
            genresList.add("Lithuanian radio");
            genresList.add("Netherlands radio");
            genresList.add("Norway radio");
            genresList.add("Polish radio");
            genresList.add("Portugal radio");
            genresList.add("Romanian radio");
            genresList.add("Russian radio");
            genresList.add("Serbian radio");
            genresList.add("Slovakian radio");
            genresList.add("Slovenian radio");
            genresList.add("Spanish radio");
            genresList.add("Swedish radio");
            genresList.add("Switzerland radio");
            genresList.add("United Kingdom radio");
            genresList.add("Ukrainian radio");
















            createRadioStations1();
            createRadioStations2();
            createRadioStations3();
            createRadioStations4();
            createRadioStations5();
            createRadioStations7();


            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int i = 0; i<totalStations.size(); i++){
                        System.out.println(genresList.get(i) + " is curently iterated");
                        for(int j = 0; j<totalStations.get(i).size(); j++){
                            int index = genresList.get(i).indexOf(" ");
                            if(index != -1){
                                System.out.println("RadioStation " + "radio" + (genresList.get(i).substring(0, index) + j + "  = new RadioStation();"));
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("RadioStation " + "radio" + (genresList.get(i) + j + "  = new RadioStation();"));
                            }

                            System.out.println("radio" + genresList.get(i) + j + ".mCustom = false;");
                            System.out.println("radio" + genresList.get(i) + j + ".mName = \"" + totalStations.get(i).get(j).mName + "\";");
                            System.out.println("radio" + genresList.get(i) + j + ".mUrl = \"" + totalStations.get(i).get(j).mUrl + "\";");
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }).start();





}
```

Comment: Where are your genreList and totalStation declared? This code doesn't make any sense to me. Why are you iterating through an array and getting the values from another one? Are the arrays the same size (otherwise it's gonna crash at some point)

Comment: I have edited to clarify the question

Comment: genresList is just to store names of genres

Comment: totalStations is an ArrayList<ArrayList<RadioStation>> that contains lists with radiostations by genre

Comment: Your number of arrays is mad! Where do you get the information about every stations? Probably you should store your data in a local database or rethink how you get your information (if it's from an API). But definitively the structure of your code is wrong, that why you can't achieve what you want.

Comment: I have added all objects in this arrays manually, so the problem is that android can't handly so many lists?

Comment: As Ben P. said : "Android can handle lists with millions of items"

Comment: No it can. Just it's not necessary to load so many data in memory if you need only a part of it. For example you have a first screen with all the types. (The types are just screen not the entire lists of stations) So you load an array with all the types only (german, top. ...). Then the user chooses one type and you display all the possible stations for this type. So you load only the array for this type. And so one. But don't create all the stations and everything when you don't need them! 
And if they are hardcoded in your app uses a database

Comment: That why I said you need to rethink your architecture as you're using a lot a resources (time/calculation, and memory) when it's not necessary. So it slows everything plus it's difficult for you to manage it

Comment: Ok, there are 1000 obects in 41 lists and I have received answers telling me that its not a big deal for android to process this amount of information, I have tried all suggestions and none worked out.

Comment: I think you need to give more information on what you're trying to do and how you get the data if you want us to help you. 1k objects is maybe not a big deal for Android but it's not a good practice to create useless things as it can ends with a lot of memory used for nothing and slows your app, especially on old devices. Plus generating the arrays as you do is very difficult to read and maintain as you can easily skip one by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over every station inside every list in `totalStations`, you could use the for-each pattern:

```
for (List<RadioStation> stations : totalStations) {
    for (RadioStation station : stations) {
        // do something with station
    }
}
```

If, for some reason, you need access to the **position** of the various items, you would want to use a traditional for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalStations.size(); i++) {
    List<RadioStation> stations = totalStations.get(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < stations.size(); j++) {
        RadioStation station = stations.get(j);
        // do something with station
    }
}
```

Comment: totalstations doesn't contain lists of String objects, this job does genresList, it contains names of genres, so everything is fine with it in my code. The problem is that this for loop can't finish iterations and skips some iterations

Comment: Its not necessary, I have tried the same code but with only one iteration and it works just fine, as it was intended but till 50th iteration, then it skips everything to the end

Comment: There are 40 lists that contain in total 1000 objects, maybe its too much for android?

Comment: No. Android can handle lists with millions of items.

Comment: @KarlssonMakhno So you have two things: `totalStations` and `genresList`. `totalStations` appears to be a `List<List<SomeObject>>` while `genresList` appears to be a `List<String>`. Is that accurate? For your original problem, which of these lists are you trying to iterate over?

Comment: You are correct, i am trying to iterate through totalStations

Comment: You want to iterate through each list within `totalStations`, right? Hence the double-nested `for` loop. What do you want to do with each `SomeObject` inside the second loop?

Comment: You are totally correct, I want to print them through System.out.println

Comment: The outcome is the same

Comment: Then the problem is elsewhere in your code. Perhaps your calls like `createRadioStations1()` need to be fixed.

Comment: Its impossible, Im using that code to populate lists of radiostations by genre and I use those lists to add them to listview and then play stream from radiostation and everything works just fine